# Resize an image based on the size of the DIV it is in with CSS?

Tags: css

Below is an image of a blog I am working on.  I need help with some CSS though.  In the top image you can see what happens to my avatar when the text body to the right of it is larger then the image.

The bottom image is how I want it to look.

My problem is there are multiple authors, so the body text to the right can be of different lengths depending on the author.  I would like to somehow have the image re-size itself to always fit into the div and look like it does in the bottom image.

Hopefully that all made sense, if anyone knows how to do this I would appreciate any help

I also put some example code up here to see it live http://dabblet.com/gist/2050005

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Force the image to a specific size, regardless of the size of the original.

css:

```
.size-image img {
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
}
```

Size being whatever size you need/want to fill.  In the html just add the class to the `img` element.

```
<img src="path/to/image" class="size-image" />
```

Then any image put into that element, whether by jquery, php or whatever, the element is sized to specifically what you need/want.

You can also put the image in it's own container, say "left-container" and have the width of the left container a specific width with an auto height, only put the `<img>` tag in the left container and the text in the "right-container"

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks for your help, my problem right now is if I were to set it to 200px, I am not sure how long there bio info is going to be, so if it were longer it could stretch even larger, or it could be a lot smaller.  Maybe if I set the `max-width` and `max-height` would fix this issue

Comment: Then try the left/right container idea. create a parent `div` then a `div` as a left container, which will contain the `img` and the right container which will house the text.  Even if the size of the text is greater than the size of the image, it will always stay in it's container.  Just make sure to float the left container to float-left then in the next `div` OUTSIDE the containers `div` make sure to clear that float

Comment: Thinking about it, to "dynamically" change the size of the image, you can do width: 100% and height: 100% but the problem is, if the width of the image element or it's containing div, stops it from growing (because of the text to the right) the the height of the image will stay constraint to width.  You should focus on the containers rather than resizing an image. Besides you lose image quality when stretching pictures

Answer (score 1):

This will work for you ..

Use css for setting

img {
    max-width: 100%; 
    max-height:100%
}

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just do:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            #img-div { width: 250px; }
            #img-div img { width: 100%; }
            #text-div {  }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="img-div">
            <img src="example.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div id="text-div">
            Lorem ipsum dolor blah blah blah
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

That works for me.  The only issue is when the actual image is smaller than the width of the containing `div`, then it gets pixelated.

Answer (score 0):

I am using this:

```
.product p.image {
text-align: center;
width: 220px;
height: 160px;
overflow: hidden;
}
.product p.image img{
max-width: 100%;
max-height: 100%;
}
```