# Resize all images in a div as the window size changes

Tags: jquery, html, css, image, scale

I have an image that I created to be a home page. I used Photoshop to slice it up and saved it as a set of styled div's. Typically when I make a website of this nature, I create a few different sizes and use javascript to detect the available window size and load the appropriate page. I want to step up my game and do the same style website but use some form of jquery to re-size all images while constraining proportions as the screen gets smaller/larger.The website could have a maximum size and become smaller, maybe even load a maximum size depending on available screen width/height.

Right now I found a plugin called [jquery-imagefit](http://www.ollicle.com/projects/jquery/imagefit/eg/) and it does a great job at scaling the images with the window size change. For some reason when I implemented it, the images separate from one another creating gaps between each image.

Can anyone help me implement imagefit into this website. Ideally the image would float at the bottom of the screen and grow and shrink from there. Here is a link to the page:

http://www.uvm.edu/~areid/homesite/div-style/index.html

thanks

katie

Comment: I guess I don't get it, why are you chopping up the images and putting them in separate divs?  Why not have a background image that is responsive?

Comment: The images stay in the same place because you are using `position:absolute;` in your CSS

Comment: @lokase http://www.uvm.edu/~areid/homesite/index.html that is the final product i am sort of going for - i just want it to be able to shrink/grow

Comment: @twiz - thank you for pointing that out. I removed the position:absolute and found that the image fell apart. Is there a way to retain the image and allow it to scale?

Comment: I assume your goal is to convert the site into a table-less layout? You could use CSS with `float` and `clear` to create the same effect. To allow for scaling, you could simply use percent values on the height/width styles for your images.

Comment: @twiz that is exactly what I am trying to do. Can you show me a simple demo of how to use float and clear to achieve this result?

Comment: You might want to take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9746342/resize-an-image-based-on-the-size-of-the-div-it-is-in-with-css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I suggested above, you can use CSS floats to organize the images and size them using percentages.

I typed up some code that may help you.

HTML:

```
<div class="everything">

    <div class="row">
        <img src="http://www.uvm.edu/~areid/homesite/div-style/images/01.gif" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <img src="http://www.uvm.edu/~areid/homesite/div-style/images/02.gif" style="width:31%">
        <img src="http://www.uvm.edu/~areid/homesite/div-style/images/forehead-mouse.gif" style="width:38%">
        <img src="http://www.uvm.edu/~areid/homesite/div-style/images/04.gif" style="width:31%">
    </div>

</div>​
```

CSS:

```
.everything{
    width:100%;
}

.row{
    overflow:hidden;
}

.row img{
    float:left;
}​
```

You can view it on JSfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/9MEn7/5/

Obviously that isn't a complete solution I created, but it should get you started. I would suggest that you cut up the images in a more practical manner, such as making the images in a "row" the same height.

Answer (score 0):

If am understanding you correctly try not to apply a width in the image tag and set your CSS of the DIV to:

```
#divID img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```